# implement similar thing like "help" command in python interactive shell

Tags: python

I am implementing a shell which does similarly like python interactive shell.

I am using raw_input and cmd2 library for it, now I need to implement a function which does exactly like "help" command. That is, it can show a large chunk of text which may exceed screen height and allow user to scroll down/up, and support Linux shell short-cut as well.

I don't know if I can do it without involving curse library. If I have to, any suggestions to integrate it with raw_input, cmd2 library?

thanks

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what you mean with a plain text library, and what you want to avoid with a curses library?

Comment: Bindings to curses is part of Pythons stand lib and it's really not that bad http://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html

Comment: `more` does not let you scroll up--only down. Perhaps you're referring to `less`?

Comment: @Krumelur please see my updates

Comment: others, please see my comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python's `help` command actually uses `less` (or `more` on some platforms) behind the scenes. You can access the same functionality:

```
import pydoc
pydoc.pager("A very long string")
```

Comment: Can't believe it's simple like this! next time I should ask my question in a direct way. thank you